# Removing first value from Firebase reference?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking for something like this:

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://myproj.firebaseio.com/groceries");
ref.limitToFirst(1).removeValue();
```

Unfortunately, `ref.limitToFirst(1).removeValue();` doesn't exist, only `ref.removeValue()` does. I want to remove only the first value! How can I do that? I'm sure it's easy & straightforward.

Comment: Aren't references unordered? What do you mean, doesn't exist? The method call? Read the documentation of the type of class `limitToFirst` returns

Comment: @cricket_007 This was just an example. I want to remove the first value inside `groceries`: the one on top of the tree in Firebase. References are ordered, because `ref.limitToFirst(1)` works...

Comment: Did you try `limitToFirst(1).getRef().removeValue()`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'll try it.

Comment: @cricket_007 since `getRef()` on a query just returns the location where that query is executed, your code will delete all child nodes. Deleting a child node requires that you have a reference to that child node. I'll write an answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only all `removeValue()` on a `DatabaseReference`. Calling `limitToFirst(1)` returns a `Query`, which does not implement `removeValue()`.

Calling `getRef()` on that query also won't work, since `Query.getRef()` returns the location where you executed the query. In other words `limitToFirst(1).getRef().removeValue()` will remove the entire location, not just the first child.

To delete a specific child node, you will first need to get a `DatabaseReference` to that child node. And this requires that you execute the query, because only then will you know what child nodes match the query:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://myproj.firebaseio.com/groceries");
Query query = ref.limitToFirst(1);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            childSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }
```

The loop over `getChildren()` is needed since a query can potentially match multiple child nodes. While your query will match at most one child node, in general there can be any number of results, so the code handles that.

Comment: I don't want to remove the value when there's a data change. I want my own if statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what should I do in my case? Please advise.

Comment: Did you try the code? The listener fires even when there is no change.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't want to detect change at all.

Comment: Yes, I did... :(

Comment: And what did it do? If you want someone to help, you'll have to be a bit more descriptive. The code I gave queries the first item and then deletes that. What happens when you run it? Did you step through it in a debugger? I just made a change that might be what is still wrong with it. But without you telling more, it's hard to help.